# VDS provider blocking port that I need. How to forwarded over other VPS

Tags: vpn, routing, vps, port-forwarding, ip-forward

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I was surprised to get to know that the VDS provider blocking port that I must to have opened. There is no way for me to push them to open it. I have to organize that port forwarding to another machine with internet. VPN is not an option I need to feed only one port from that external machine the rest of the traffic I would like to use in a regular way. What could be a solution? Is that possible to run only one specific service/program under VPN or to feed only one specific port through another machine with Internet were all ports are opened?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify? What's a "VDS" provider?

Comment: It doesn´t clarify anything I mean the name of the company I already call them they said that because of the security reasons they will not open that port so there is no way to open it but the app that I am using need that port opened there is no way to use alternative port. I was thinking to change routes and use another VPS to make a port tunneling on that VPS because there all ports are opened.